# Solving $a + b x = c y$ in the integer domain for general $a$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I have the following equation:

$\frac{a + b x}{c} \in \mathbb{N}$ where $a,b,c,x \in \mathbb{N}$.

and I want to find all x that satisfy these requirements. This should be the same as:

$a + b x = c y,~~~ y \in \mathbb{N}$

This looks like a linear Diophantine equation, but Bézout's identity cannot be used since $a$ is not necessarily $\gcd(b, c)$.

How can I solve for $x$?

Comment: if $a$ is not a multiple of $\gcd(b,c)$, can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent to asking when $bx\equiv -a\pmod{c}$.

In the case $b$ and $c$ are coprime, the problem would be easy, since $x\equiv -ab^{-1}$.

[This](http://www.math.niu.edu/~buck/420/modequations.pdf) seems to be decent introduction to solving linear modular equations.

Comment: If $b$ and $c$ are not coprime then it follows that $\gcd(b,c)$ divides $a$. Therefore, if $a$ is not a multiple of $\gcd(b,c)$ there is no solution. If it is a multiple, just divide the equation throughout by $\gcd$ and the problem is reduced to your answer.

Comment: Thank you both, this really helps!